# Windows Phone 7 Alarm does not goes off at scheduled time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, alarm

I'm creating an app for windows phone OS 7.1 to learn about this platform. When creating alarm app, i faced this strange error: When i set an alarm using ScheduledActionService.Add(myAlarm), alarm never goes off at the selected time. I set the beginTime = now + 10 seconds, then i waited for 2 minutes with no luck. However when i add another alarm in runtime, after the selected time of the last alarm, then the last alarm will goes off.

Below is the code of my createAlarm function. I've done some searches but found no solution.

```
        private void createAlarm(double time, string message)
    {
        var myAlarm = new Alarm(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        {
            Content = message,
            BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time),
            ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(time + 10.0)
        };

        myAlarm.Sound = new Uri("/Sounds/02 Ha Trang.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
        myAlarm.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;

        ScheduledActionService.Add(myAlarm);
    }
```

Comment: With debug, i found that when i add another alarm after the begin time of first alarm, then first alarm will fire when the program execute line "ScheduledActionService.Add(myAlarm);"

Comment: I tried this exact same code and the alarm went off at the exact time it should have! Ofcourse I commented out the Sound part coz I don't have that file.

Comment: @Saurabh May i ask you about version of visual studio, SDK and emulator you are using? I downloaded window phone SDK 7.1 with VS express in it. It might be because of my system...

Comment: I know from my own testing that toast messages have a minimum delay of 30 seconds or a minute. Its possible that now + 10 seconds is too short a delay.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 professional edition, with Windows phone 7.1.1 SDK, the one for Tango Refresh! Use the standard emulator.

Comment: @user2006147 : any luck?

Comment: @Saurabh i've sent the xap file to my friend with a windows phone to test the app. I'm coding other functions while waiting for his response. Thanks for your concern. Maybe i will reinstall everything after finishing this application.

Comment: let us know how it goes! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem. Alarms go off with accuracy of 30 seconds. So is the case with the reminders. You may actually get accurate results sometimes, but overall, it's not reliable to have frequent alarms or reminders. The lack of accuracy is probably to keep resource consumption low. (Remember, alarms work in background.) The first alarm is fired when second one is set because system suddenly 'realizes' that an alarm is already overdue. It would be a good practice to separate those with at least a minute.

On the other hand, if you really need to have a beep at really small intervals, you will have to use something more 'foreground' like timer.